# Graphics card driver software

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, cpu, ubuntu-14.04

I have the following specs on my system76 laptop (Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit)

- Intel® Iris™ Pro Graphics 5200
- 4th Generation Intel® Core™ i7-4750HQProcessor ( 2.0 GHz 6MB L3 Cache - 4 Cores plus Hyperthreading )
- 16 GB Dual Channel DDR3 SDRAM at 1600MHz - 2 X 8 GB

Is there any kind of software tweaks I can do to enhance the quality of the images that come in on my graphics card from when I play steam. Please suggest any kind of package(s) or modifications I can do that will give me a better picture/resolution/display.

Comment: Just install the current drivers that about all you can do

Comment: I already have the current driver installed, what I'm asking is if there is any kind of modification I can do to the current driver software that will increase it's performance.

Comment: There were tweaks for the 950 driver using the xorg.conf file settings. You could start by looking there. Also take a look here http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_iris5200_win8redux&num=1 Particularly the drivers and versions used.

Comment: Thanks, much. So according to the article provided, if i was to adjust the resolution size relative to the game I am playing, I would see more optimal results?

Comment: That's pretty much a given. Lower resolution means less work for the graphics chip. Are you using the same drivers as mentioned in that link?

Comment: Yes I am, I will give that a shot today. At first I was thinking about overclocking the graphics card, but I dont want to do something that can potentially be catastrophic, especially since I'm not all too familiar with what to adjust the graphics card and fan to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real thing you can do is open the "Intel Graphics and Media Control Panel" program which ships with that particular graphics driver (both windows and linux according to Intels website)

From within there, you should be able to play with your configuration until you get something which works for you. I can't recommend anything specific as its all personal preference stuff.

To be honest, beyond ensuring that you have the latest drivers installed - there really isn't a lot you can do.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look. I just got a new game and the graphics are really good but the display on my PC is not the greatest.

Comment: @user3299512 - It sounds like the GPU you have barely supports this new game's specification which is typical for Intel's GPU product line.

Comment: I still get a picture but i sometimes see black lines as if the screen is still rendering. Do you know of any articles that show how to overclock the card?